# In app native share dialog and google+ signin in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, share, google-plus-signin

I want to share via inApp native share dialog from google+ but as stated in documentation it requires google sign in. But I don't want to provide a seperate google sign in button for the same. So, Is it possible to go to safari for google+ sign in (if not signed in already), revert back to app and open the share dialog in app?

Also, I need to know which function from google+ ios sdk handles silent authentication and hence provide me the place to write my in app native share dialog code?

Comment: Take a look in the documentation. The silent auth is documented...

Comment: I have seen silent auth documentation. It talks about automatic login of user if app has already been authorised before only then it comes to - (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error: (NSError *) error method. What about if you want to have in app sign in page if not logged in like in app share in native dialog?

Comment: You have to sign in once with the mobile sdk. It's the sdk that handles the session on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. On Click of share button :

Check if its logged in already. this is handled by the sdk, but one needs to do this:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
[signIn authenticate];

signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;


signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];  // "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login" scope

// Optional: declare signIn.actions, see "app activities"
signIn.delegate = self;
```

Now, we see it redirects to safari google+ login if app not approved for the first time. After approving the app, it redirects to app back with delegate method in which the native share dialog can be implemented:

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth: (GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
               error: (NSError *) error {
id<GPPShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];

// Set any prefilled text that you might want to suggest
[shareBuilder setPrefillText:@"Please visit http://abcd.in to view my listing"];

[shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abcd.in"]];

[shareBuilder open];
NSLog(@"Received error %@ and auth object %@",error, auth);
}
```